# how to add limit 0 to transaction_code using str_pad laravel

Tags: laravel

```
//Generate nomor nota
    $data = Penjualan::count();
    if ($data == null) {
        $numb = '001';
        $transcation_code = 'NT' . $numb;
    }else {
        $last = Penjualan::orderBy('id_penjualan', 'desc')->first()->no_nota;
        $lastNumb = substr($last, -3);
        $transcation_code = 'NT'. str_pad($lastNumb + 1, 0, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

i have any problem,
when my transaction_code reaches 999, in the next my transaction_code is 100 not 1000